# Puppet Operation not permitted on owner/group change

Tags: puppet, nfs, vagrant

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with vboxheadless 4.2.10 and vagrant 1.2.7 to provision instances on a server.

When I run vagrant up I get the following errors:

```
err: /Stage[main]//File[/var/www/example.drupal.dev]/owner: change from 110 to vagrant failed: Failed to set owner to '1000': Operation not permitted - /var/www/example.drupal.dev
err: /Stage[main]//File[/var/www/example.drupal.dev]/group: change from 119 to vagrant failed: Failed to set group to '1000': Operation not permitted - /var/www/example.drupal.dev
```

Here is the offending puppet conf:

```
file { "/var/www/example.drupal.dev":
  ensure => "directory",
  owner => "vagrant",
  group => "vagrant"
}
```

It's mounting through NFS.

The rest of the box provisions fine but this is causing issues when I run my tests. I don't see these issues on OSX or Windows but see it on Ubuntu 12.04. This post ([Vagrant OS X host nfs share permissions error - Failed to set owner to '1000'](https://serverfault.com/questions/487862/vagrant-os-x-host-nfs-share-permissions-error-failed-to-set-owner-to-1000)) references no_root_squash but you can't apply that because the exports are regenerated on box reload.

I'm unsure how to fix this so would appreciate any help.

Comment: What kind of filesystem is `/var/www/example.drupal.dev` on?  What happens when you manually try to change the ownership using `chown`?  If this is coming from NFS, then why aren't you changing things on the NFS server?

Comment: It's an NFS link between ext4 and ext4 on the guest box.

Comment: Same exact issue. Did you have any luck?

Answer (score 1):

You must set **no_root_squash** flag to allow ownership change. See answers here: 
[Vagrant OS X host nfs share permissions error - Failed to set owner to '1000'](https://serverfault.com/questions/487862/vagrant-os-x-host-nfs-share-permissions-error-failed-to-set-owner-to-1000)